# Detectar posição de slide no plugin JQuery SLY

Tags: jquery, plugin, javascript-eventos, slideshow

Olá.
Gostaria de saber como eu detecto a posição atual de um slide usando o plugin Sly.

O tipo que uso é 'oneperframe'.
Eu nao tenho muito conhecimento de jquery, e menos ainda com esse plugin.
Eu visitei http://darsa.in/sly/#!documentation mas nao foi muito didático.
....

Caso ninguém saiba, mas tenha conhecimento de um slideshow(por conteúdo HTML e não apenas imagens) semelhante a esse em que eu possa detectar a posicao do slide toda vez que eu mudar(onscroll), também é bem vindo. obrigado.

Comment: Viu [essa propriedade](https://github.com/darsain/sly/blob/master/docs/Properties.md#slypos) e [esse evento](https://github.com/darsain/sly/blob/master/docs/Events.md#change)?

Comment: Sim, mas tentei implementar de vários modos. O mais próximo q consegui foi executar um alert(substituindo o console.log) só uma vez (onload). O q eu queria é algo como um eventlistening, toda vez que o usuário mover o slide, retornar o valor do slide em exibição.

Comment: Foi o link que mostrei: [evento de change](https://github.com/darsain/sly/blob/master/docs/Events.md#change). Edite a pergunta e inclua o código do que já tentou, mesmo que esteja errado. Assim pode-se fornecer uma resposta a partir do seu código.

Answer (score 0):

Por conta própria eu consegui. Fui tentando e tentando e achei uma parte do código original que é executada a cada mudança de slide.

**1.** Vá ao arquivo *sly.min.js*. Encontre o seguinte trecho:

*(e&&(a=Ib[d.centerItem].center),Pb&&rb.activateMiddle&&T(d.centerItem)):e&&(a=Ib[d.firstItem].start)}*

**2.** Nessa parte final, **start)}**, antes do } coloque **;** e insira sua função. Identifiquei duas variáveis, **Jb.activeItem** e **sb.pos**. Eu fiz o seguinte:
....**firstItem].start); funcao(Jb.activeItem);}**

Essa parte é executada a cada movimento, ou seja, em tempo real. Numa única mudança de slide, esse trecho é executado dezenas de vezes. Logo, quem quiser usar, terá de criar uma função de controle, para executar um comando apenas quando houver alteração de slide (Jb.activeItem). Pronto, a parte mais difícil já está resolvida.